# Adding a Service Fabric service to System Application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to add a service to the System application of the SF or is that a no go scenario? What I'd like to do is to have a meta-data services about other applications in the cluster, where the service can be queried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system services are built into the cluster and are not extensible. You can certainly build an application that offers centralized metadata about other applications/services in the cluster but you would need to maintain that metadata yourself.

Comment: Maintaining data about various apps/services, any recommended method or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Not really - you'd just have an app with a stateful service that collects the data, either by polling or having it pushed, and then serves it up to others. Out of curiosity, what kind of metadata are you looking to manage? Is it custom metadata? All of the state that the system itself understands is already available through the REST API.

Comment: That would be custom metadata about the tenants. The REST API you've mentioned, what is it and does it have a .NET equivalent?

Comment: Look under the Reference header in the left-nav of the [doc page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/service-fabric/). You'll see links to reference docs for the various management options: REST, PowerShell, and System.Fabric. All three offer the same management capabilities.

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you Sean. Just wish .NET doco wouldn't be that dry and minimalistic :)